# union vs union all on memory efficiency?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The intermedia cypher query class from neo4j has a section called subquery and it mentioned:

"
Combining query results with UNION
As your queries become more complex, you may need to combine the results of multiple queries. You can do so with UNION. With UNION, the queries you are combining must return the same number of properties or data

Here is a simple example:

```
MATCH (m:Movie) WHERE m.year = 2000
RETURN {type:"movies", theMovies: collect(m.title)} AS data
UNION ALL
MATCH (a:Actor) WHERE a.born.year > 2000
RETURN { type:"actors", theActors: collect(DISTINCT a.name)} AS data
```

The first query returns an object with a type property of "movies" and a theMovies property that is a list of movies. It returns this object as a variable named Data

The second query returns an object with a type property of "actors" and a theActors property that is a list of actor names. It returns this object as a variable named Data

Because both queries return a variable named Data, we can combine the results using UNION ALL.

UNION ALL returns all results which is more efficient on memory but can lead to duplicates. UNION returns distinct results."

What is the union all compared with? Is it comparing with union? Why UNION ALL is more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of neo4j, but let me explain `UNION` and `UNION ALL` in terms of `SQL`.

Using `UNION` would remove all the duplicate records where the data in all of the columns are the same, while `UNION ALL` does not remove them, it just simply combines the data and returns them.

When we use `UNION`, the database server needs to identify the duplicate records and to keep only one of them in the results, the database server must do additional work to remove the duplicate rows.

This additional workload is usually following:
`UNION` first performs a sorting operation and eliminates the records that are duplicated across all columns before finally returning the combined data set.

```
SELECT 'abc' AS col UNION SELECT 'abc' AS col

+-----+
| col |
+------+
| abc |
+-----+
```

Observe the difference in results. The above query uses `UNION`, and the below one uses `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT 'abc' AS col UNION ALL SELECT 'abc' AS col

+-----+
| col |
+-----+
| abc |
+-----+
| abc |
+-----+
```

This additional workload adds more time while using `UNION`, and that's why it is slightly less efficient and time consuming operation than `UNION ALL`. But, `UNION ALL` would return all the records being combined, and duplicate records might come. While, `UNION` returns distinct records only after combining all the records altogether.

Comment: Hope this might help you slightly, I tried explaining in terms of SQL.